# Creating tuples of column names and last value from each value of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Assume an interface outputs a pandas dataframe like

```
   df
   A  B
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```

And for further processing, only tuples consisting of the column name and the last value of each columns are needed, i.e.

```
A_tuple
('A', 3)
B_tuple
('B', 6)
```

How can I get these tuples in a concise way from the original dataframe?

Comment: Thanks! Just corrected it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
In [188]: df.iloc[-1].reset_index().apply(tuple, axis=1)
Out[188]:
0    (A, 3)
1    (B, 6)
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3):

Another method is to call `apply` on the df so it iterates over each column and just access the last value using `[-1]` and the column name via attribute `.name`:

```
In [208]:
df.apply(lambda x:(x.name ,x.iloc[-1]))

Out[208]:
A    (A, 3)
B    (B, 6)
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another approach:

```
df.to_dict('record')[-1].items()
```

Which gives:

```
[('A', 3), ('B', 6)]
```